# Setup a streaming server

Tags: linux, nginx, rtmp, http-streaming

I would like to setup a streaming server, with RTMP and HLS protocols (and with Nginx). For that, I have a VPS (running Debian). I succeed to make everything works, but I still have an important security problem: anyone can use my server to stream with, without streaming key or other passwords.

So here is my problem: I would like to setup a server as it follows.

- RTMP encoding an ingetsion requiring a single keypass;
- Conversion to HLS;
- Access to playing without requiring keypass, using a player (videojs).
  Could you help me?

Thanks.